# HTML and CSS table calendar not working

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am supposed to be designing a calendar for a business and it's upcoming events and list them in the calendar on their scheduled day. I have the following code below:

the table:

```
<table class="calendar">
        <caption>Events in February at the CCC</caption>

        <colgroup>
            <col class="weekdays" colspan="5" />
            <col class="weekends" colspan="2" />
        </colgroup>

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Sun</th>
                <th>Mon</th>
                <th>Tue</th>
                <th>Wed</th>
                <th>Thu</th>
                <th>Fri</th>
                <th>Sat</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

     <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>26</td>
            <td>27</td>
            <td>28</td>
            <td>29</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>31</td>
            <td>1</td>
                <dl>
                    <dt>Taiwan Acrobats</dt>
                    <dd>8 pm</dd>
                    <dd>$16/$24/$32</dd>
                </dl>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
                <dl>
                    <dt>Carson Quartet</dt>
                    <dd>1 pm</dd>
                    <dd>$8</dd>
                </dl>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
                <dl>
                    <dt>Joey Gallaway</dt>
                    <dd>8 pm</dd>
                    <dd>$16/$24/$36</dd>
                </dl>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>7</td>
                <dl>
                    <dt>West Side Story</dt>
                    <dd>7 pm</dd>
                    <dd>$24/$36/$64</dd>
                </dl>
            <td>8</td>
                <dl>
                    <dt>West Side Story</dt>
                    <dd>7 pm</dd>
                    <dd>$24/$36/$64</dd>
                </dl>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>9</td>
                <dt>Carson Quartet</dt>
                    <dd>1 pm</dd>
                    <dd>$8</dd>
            <td>10</td>
                <dl>
                    <dt>Jazz Masters</dt>
                    <dd>8 pm</dd>
                    <dd>$16/$24/$32</dd>
                </dl>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>13</td>
                <dl>
                    <dt>Harlem Choir</dt>
                    <dd>8 pm</dd>
                    <dd>$16/$24/$32</dd>
                </dl>
            <td>14</td>
                <dl>
                    <dt>Chamberlain Symphony</dt>
                    <dd>8 pm</dd>
                    <dd>$16/$24/$32</dd>
                </dl>
            <td>15</td>
                <dl>
                    <dt>Edwin Ovood</dt>
                    <dd>8 pm</dd>
                    <dd>$24/$36/$64</dd>
                </dl>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>16</td>
                <dl>
                    <dt>Carson Quartet</dt>
                    <dd>1 pm</dd>
                    <dd>$8</dd>
                </dl>
            <td>17</td>
            <td>18</td>
            <td>19</td>
                <dl>
                    <dt>The Yearling</dt>
                    <dd>7 pm</dd>
                    <dd>$8/$14/$18</dd>
                </dl>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>21</td>
                <dl>
                    <dt>An Ellington Tribute</dt>
                    <dd>8 pm</dd>
                    <dd>$24/$32/$48</dd>
                </dl>
            <td>22</td>
                <dl>
                    <dt>Othella</dt>
                    <dd>8 pm</dd>
                    <dd>$18/$28/$42</dd>
                </dl>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>23</td>
                <dl>
                    <dt>Carson Quartet</dt>
                    <dd>1 pm</dd>
                    <dd>$8</dd>
                </dl>
            <td>24</td>
            <td>25</td>
                <dl>
                    <dt>Madtown Jugglers</dt>
                    <dd>8 pm</dd>
                    <dd>$12/$16/$20</dd>
                </dl>
            <td>26</td>
            <td>27</td>
            <td>28</td>
                <dl>
                    <dt>Ralph Williams</dt>
                    <dd>8 pm</dd>
                    <dd>$32/$48/$64</dd>
                </dl>
            <td>1</td>
                <dl>
                    <dt>Othella</dt>
                    <dd>8 pm</dd>
                    <dd>$16/$28/$42</dd>
                </dl>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
     </table>
```

Here are the styles for the table:

```
table.calendar {
border-spacing: 5px;
font-size: 8px;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
padding: 40px;
width: 650px;

}

table.calendar caption {
text-align: center;
padding-bottom: 10px;
font-size: 16px;
letter-spacing: 3px;
width: 650px;
}

table.calendar td{
width: 14%;
}

table.calendar col.weekends {
background-color: rgb(255, 232, 232);
}

table.calendar thead {
background-color: red;
color: white;
letter-spacing: 5px;
}

table.calendar thead tr {
height: 5%;
}

table.calendar tbody tr {
height: 19%;
}

table.calendar th, table.calendar td {
border: 1px solid gray;
vertical-align: top;
}

table.calendar h3 {
font-size: 8px;
}
```

With this code, I get a calendar with the table data outside of the calendar. It is listed above the calendar in the page. How do I fix this?

Comment: Please give your question a more descriptive title. Also, please create a subset of your code (about 10%) to make it easier for folks to look over.

Comment: Your markup is invalid. Look a little closer at how you added the `<dl>` elements, respective to the table cells.

Comment: Run your code through an [HTML validator](https://html5.validator.nu) to make sure there are no errors there.

Answer (score 0):

include `<dl>....</dl>` inside `<td> .... </td>` tag to include your event into particular cell. [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/kriyeta/muuw4h5m/1/)
like:

```
         <td>1
            <dl>
                <dt>Taiwan Acrobats</dt>
                <dd>8 pm</dd>
                <dd>$16/$24/$32</dd>
            </dl>
          </td>
```